# Upload large file (sqldatabase.bak 15gb) to Amazon S3

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using EC2 with a Windows Server 2012 R2 instance. I'm trying to upload a large backup of my database (15gb `.bak` file) to Amazon S3.

I'm using a `.bat` script that use `dgsync.exe` :

```
SET DGTOOLS_ACCESS_KEY=***
SET DGTOOLS_SECRET_KEY=****
SET DGTOOLS_ENCRYPTION_PASSWORD=***
SET DGTOOLS_DECRYPTION_PASSWORD_0=****
SET DGTOOLS_DECRYPTION_PASSWORD_1=****

dgsync.exe -z -l --dont-delete --rrs "E:/BAK_ASO" "s3://bucket-backup-s3/Backup ATLAS/BAK_ASO/"
```

It's working for my other database (less than 5gb) but not for the big one (15gb).

Some people tell me to split my database but I don't want to corrupt my file, what can I do ?

Comment: not sure dgsync supports multipart upload, otherwise use aws S3 CLI and [create multipart upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/create-multipart-upload.html)

Comment: thanks ! i will try it